# \IfTargetDateBefore doesn't use dates from \DeclareRelease and \DeclareCurrentRelease

Tags: package-writing, latex-base

I am a little confused with the rollback mechanism in LaTeX. I want to let users test the future breaking changes of my package and also I want to keep the future changes in the same package file. So I tried the following demo file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[force]{demo.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018-04-01]
\DeclareRelease{v2026}{2026-01-01}{demo.sty}
\DeclareCurrentRelease{}{2022-01-01}
\IfTargetDateBefore{2026-01-01}{\newcommand\test{old}}{\newcommand\test{new}}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{demo}[=v2026] % the result is "new" even if I write \IfTargetDateBefore{2027-01-01}

%\usepackage{demo}[=2026-01-01] % the result is "new"

%\usepackage{demo} % the result is "new" but I expect it would be "old"

%\usepackage{demo}[=2022-01-01] % ! LaTeX Error: Suspicious rollback date given.

\begin{document}

\test

\end{document}
```

The questions are:

(1) Is it correct to make `\DeclareRelease` use the same package file as `\DeclareCurrentRelease`?

(2) Why `\IfTargetDateBefore` doesn't use the dates in `\DeclareRelease` and `\DeclareCurrentRelease` as target dates?

(3) For `\DeclareRelease`, I have given both `name` and `date` in declaring a release, but it is strange that `\usepackage{demo}[=<name>]` and `\usepackage{demo}[=<date>]` still behave differently.

**[Update]** Based on the answer of Frank Mittelbach, I have another question:

(4) Is it a good idea to provide `\DeclareFutureRelease{<name>}{<date>}` command after `\DeclareCurrentRelease` for this use case? This command doesn't include a `<file>` argument, and it only maps the `<name>` to `<date>` so that `\IfTargetDateBefore` can use it. In general, `<name>` such as `beta` is much easier to remember than `<date>` such as `2026-01-01`.

Comment: I've asked the relevant team members for feedback here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rollback mechanism in LaTeX is a lightweight "roll back" mechanism, not a roll forward one, even though it does support rolling forward in a limited restricted way.

In particular it only applies if there is an explicit request for a dated roll back, but it does *not* do anything if not, and if you have a request for a named version then it just jumps to that version and again doesn't look at dates.

Furthermore all release dates have to be (as documented) in increasing order, e.g., you can't have a current release of 2022 and a previous of 2026. See
https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2018-FMi-TUB-tb122mitt-version-rollback.pdf.

I have augmented your example a bit and commented on the cases, hope that helps.

The only form the mechanism supports "future releases" is to give them just a name but not a date, and then tell your users to try out "v2023-beta" and inside such a file  `\IfTargetDateBefore` has no effect.

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{demo.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2018-04-01]
\DeclareRelease{v2025}{2025-01-01}{demo0.sty}
\DeclareRelease{v2026}{2026-01-01}{demo.sty}
\DeclareRelease{v2027}{2027-01-01}{demo2.sty}
\DeclareCurrentRelease{}{2022-01-01}

\typeout{testing for \pkgcls@innerdate}

\IfTargetDateBefore{2025-12-31}{\renewcommand\testa{\typeout{testa=old}}}{\renewcommand\testa{\typeout{testa=new}}}
\IfTargetDateBefore{2026-01-01}{\renewcommand\testb{\typeout{testb=old}}}{\renewcommand\testb{\typeout{testb=new}}}
\IfTargetDateBefore{2027-01-01}{\renewcommand\testc{\typeout{testc=old}}}{\renewcommand\testc{\typeout{testc=new}}}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\providecommand\testa{\typeout{testa=unset}}
\providecommand\testb{\typeout{testb=unset}}
\providecommand\testc{\typeout{testc=unset}}

\makeatletter
\let\pkgcls@debug\typeout
\makeatother

\usepackage{demo}[=v2026] % the result is "new" even if I write \IfTargetDateBefore{2027-01-01}
%
% no release date give so \IfTargetDateBefore is always new because the assumption is that the named release contains the current code for that name 

%\usepackage{demo}[=2026-01-01] % the result is "new"
%
% this is correct because the new code was at 2026-01-01 and not before


\usepackage{demo} % the result is "new" but I expect it would be "old"
%
% no request for rollback so current file is used with the assumption that everything is "new" any \IfTargetDateBefore contains old code in its first argument.

%\usepackage{demo}[=2022-01-01] % ! LaTeX Error: Suspicious rollback date given.
%
% first dated release is for 2025 so LaTeX complains (because release dates have to be ordered by date).

\begin{document}

\testa \testb \testc

\end{document}
```

With the internal debugging turned on, so you get something like

```
LaTeX Warning: Writing or overwriting file `./demo.sty'.


(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
--- File loaded request (\usepackage or ...)
    1: demo
    2: 
    3: =v2026
    4: sty
(./demo.sty
---\DeclareRelease:
    1: v2025
    2: 2025-01-01
    3: demo0.sty
Label doesn't match
---\DeclareRelease:
    1: v2026
    2: 2026-01-01
    3: demo.sty
Result: use demo.sty
(./demo.sty
testing for \maxdimen 
Include code introduced on 2025-12-31
Include code introduced on 2026-01-01
Include code introduced on 2027-01-01
))
--- File loaded request (\usepackage or ...)
    1: l3backend-pdftex
    2: 
    3: 
    4: def
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./rollback.aux)
testa=new
testb=new
testc=new
```

from the above.

To answer your questions from the end of your post:

(1)  it works as long as you don't confuse the algorithm by putting the dates in random order, but it is a bit pointless as you achieve the same effect by not using that `\DeclareRelease` line at all as it will then fall through to current release and uses `\IfTargetReleaseBefore` if a dated release is  asked for.

(2) because that would require more testing and thus making each and every package processing slower (and quite frankly, because your idea was not considered as a use case).

(3) named and dated release selection behave differently because the "named" one has the assumption that the file it points to contains the "current" code for the named release so any `\IfTarget...` selected the new code branch.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your answer, I have updated my question and added question (4) about `\DeclareFutureRelease`.  What do you think of it?

Comment: @L.J.R. you are the first person who wants to used it in this fashion (I would probably just put the beta into a separate file), but yes, why not. It might not be absolutely trivial to integrate this though, because the code has the assumption that dates are all before \DeclareCurrentRelease and are earlier than that (and it shouldn't slow down standard processing) but if you want to make a proposal and offer to make a pull against the dev branch I'm happy to consider it (or if not at least make a pr for later considerations)

Comment: OK. I will try to read the code to see whether or not I can handle this case.